# Run voice commands like "Play", "Pause", "Next" on Spotify with Tasker and AutoVoice?

Tags: tasker, remote-control, spotify

When I get into my car, I connect my Nexus 5 (not rooted) on my audio system and play music with Spotify. What I want is to be able to skip, pause, and play songs with voice commands. I tried out with Tasker and AutoVoice. AutoVoice is recognizing the command, but nothing is happening. Is it possible to do that with Tasker and AutoVoice? If yes, then how?

Comment: this thing does not need rooting.

Comment: You need to make use of broadcast-intent... When you speak... check the word and accordingly broadcast the message to that particular intent which will be accepted by that application's broadcast receiver and it will work accordingly.. its simple... All you need to know is... what is the intent to broadcast out message... thats it!

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput), a plugin for Tasker available in the market, which doesn't require root.

You can then create a profile and set AutoVoice for every command, then set AutoInput (plugin section) with the X and Y coordinates of the button you want to press. Find the coordinates of the button by enabling the feature in Developer Options.

N.B. Make sure you're in the app you want when running the task.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an event using "autovoice recognize":
   set command filter = next song (or whatever you want to say as a command)
   (Everything else is left unchanged)
2. Create a new task:
   System › Send Intent
   Action= `com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.NEXT`
   Package= `com.spotify.music`
   Target= Broadcast Receiver

(Should work now)

`com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PLAY` works for "play"; never looked up anything else as I didn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

there's a great app in the play store called [Commandr](http://commandr.rsenapps.com/). it seems like it would have the functionality you want without any programming.

Commandr extends the capability of Google Now's voice recognition by adding more voice commands that Google Now can recognize. The developer adds new commands regularly and those new commands are chosen via in-app user submission and voting pages.

Comment: *We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.* -- Please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/110631/edit). Also, could you mention a brief description of this app as well? That would make it easier for a reader to know why this app would be helpful, or why should they  take a look at it!

Comment: sorry bout that. will do. at work, i'll be able to edit as soon as i leave.

Comment: the edit is done. sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

I developed an app that allows you to use voice commands for Spotify: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tmacstudios.spotifyvoice&hl=en